# Sort int (not Integer) array with custom ordering rules

Tags: java, android

I need to sort about 100000 ints with custom ordering rules. If I use Comparator, I need to have an array Integer instances, which is slower to create, slower to sort and takes more memory.

Quick benchmark on Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.2:

```
createIntArrayAndFillWith1to100000; // 18 ms
createIntegerArrayAndFillWith1to100000; // 191 ms (using Integer.valueOf(i))
Arrays.sort(randomInts); // 354 ms
Arrays.sort(randomIntegers, simpleComparator); // 1734 ms
```

Is implementing custom sort my best option?

Comment: How much slower would it be by autoboxing it?

Comment: I feel compelled to ask... is it too slow to support your application, or do you just not like the speed?

Comment: @Vipar I'm gonna test that and report back :)

Comment: I think the creation of all the Integer-Instances is more an issue (especially related to memory-usage) than the boxing

Comment: @TonyEnnis yes, I need to do this twice when the app is launched and every time some condition changes. It's definitely noticable by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way is to implement a sort-algorithm on arrays for elementar datatype *int* yourself. The Java-library does not provide versions for each  elementar datatype. boxing/unboxing is the answer.

I would simply implement a sort-algorithm for this special need. (If speed is really such important) 
Inplace-sorting with quick-sort is quite easy to implement [quicksort (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)